# Microsoft API source is not loading in pop up when we click on "Login with Microsoft Account" of windows or electron application while automating it

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, electron, winappdriver

Microsoft API source is not loading in pop up of windows or electron application while we click on "Login with Microsoft Account" when automating it. But its working fine while we opening it manually.

Possible reasons:
Seems source for login page and pop up is different and also it might due to the environment variables in .env file which contains the Microsoft API not gets loaded while automating the application.

I can't able to find solutions for above.

Issue:

1.Once application gets launched, Login button will be available

[image]

2.When we click on "Login with Microsoft account", we will get pop up with Microsoft account or login page to enter an account.

[image]

3.But, while launching the application via automation, this source not getting loaded.

[image]